# POST listener into file transfer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, post, file-transfer

I will preface this by saying I am not fluent in C# so forgive me if I am missing knowledge I should have.

I have been trying to build a program that runs all the time (just sits on a server) and every time there is a post request from a a specific IP address (aka 192.215.129.28 for example) on a specific port (445) my program would grab whatever is being posted (which should be a gziped file) and then save it to a folder on my network where this program is running.

I currently have code to listen to request on mylocal network, but when I change it to the IP I need to listen to I get

```
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.HttpListenerException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"pop up in my visual studio.
```

All I am doing is changing this line:

```
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
```

to this line

```
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://192.215.129.28:445/");
```

Which causes that error. Also unsure how to grab what was posted. Mostly trying to just solve this error though, have been struggling for hours on why the IP change breaks it.

Here is the full function just in case it is needed:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listener = new HttpListener();

            listener.Prefixes.Add("http://192.215.129.28:445/");
            listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;

            listener.Start();
            this.listenThread1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(startlistener));
            listenThread1.Start();

        }
```

Comment: And what happens if you listen on 192.215.129.28, but on 8000 port?

Comment: @Evk the exact same thing. However might be worth noting that if I wrong this listener.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:8000/"); with port 445 then it breaks in the same way. So it breaks anytime its port 445 or if I use that IP with any port.

Comment: Any changes you are running that non-evelated (i.e. not as admin)?

Comment: @Evk Program is run as an admin, had full access to everything. The IP address is a place where files come into, trying to detect when a file comes into there using this tactic.

Comment: The prefix host part (192.215.129.28) is supposed to be a local host or IP address or a DNS name that maps onto an external IP address from your host. It seems from your description that you expect it to be a remote IP address ('request from a a specific IP address '). Secondly, make sure the specified local port (e.g. 445) is not already is use by another application (e.g. IIS).

Answer (score 1):

try to use this

```
listener.Prefixes.Add("0.0.0.0:445");
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12531580)

Comment: @Console It provides an answer. Whether it is correct or not doesn't matter.